# sort arraylist of object from different class

Tags: java

I am working in RMI and I have different servers ( class ), I want to store objects from these classes in arraylist, then I want to sort them by shared methode that return some intger number.

Comment: Some example code would be helful!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these objects are of type `Foo` which does not implement `Comparable<Foo>` but does have a method `public int getBar()`, you can pass your own [`Comparator<Foo>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to [`Collections#sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) like so:

```
List<Foo> foos = /* whatever */;
Collections.sort(foos, new Comparator<Foo> () {
   @Override
   public int compare(Foo a, Foo b) {
       return Integer.compare(a.getBar(), b.getBar());
   } 
});
```

Note that [`Integer#compare(int, int)` is only since Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29). If you're using anything older, use this implementation instead:

```
   public int compare(Foo a, Foo b) {
       int x = a.getBar();
       int y = b.getBar();

       return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
   }
```

This is [exactly how `Integer#compare()` works internally](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html#1011).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that shared method is `public Integer sharedMethod()` then do the sorting as below:

```
    List<SharedClass> list = new ArraList<SharedClass>();
    ....

    //Sorting here
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<SharedClass>(){
      @Override
      public int compare(SharedClass sc1, SharedClasssc2){
          return sc1.sharedMethod().compareTo(sc1.sharedMethod());
      }
     });
```

If it is returns `int` then use `Integer.compare` method (**Java7**) as below:

```
    //Sorting here
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<SharedClass>(){
      @Override
      public int compare(SharedClass sc1, SharedClasssc2){
          return Integer.compare(sc1.sharedMethod(), sc1.sharedMethod());
      }
     });
```

If using Java Version below 7, then:

```
    //Sorting here
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<SharedClass>(){
      @Override
      public int compare(SharedClass sc1, SharedClasssc2){
          int value1 = sc1.sharedMethod();
          int value2 = sc1.sharedMethod();
          //return 1, if value1 is greater,-1 if smaller and 0 if equal to value2. 
          return (value1  < value2) ? -1 : ((value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0);
      }
     });
```

Comment: Note that every object in java already has a method that return an int : hashCode(), so we might as well use that.

Comment: @user1886012 It depends which method, attribute you want to use in sorting. As per OP, he/she wants to sort based on a shared method which returns integer.

Comment: You are correct, if he only wants the list to quickly find entries he could use hashCode. If the order is somehow semantically relevant, then hashCode is probably not a good option. (and I apologize for only now updating my user name appearance)